# align elements vertically and horizontally on list item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to have a layout where there are some list items, each one have a title like "Item 0", a `<small>` below the title, in this example with the text "Description Item 0", and then at right of this text "Item 0" and "Item 0 Description" I want a select menu and at right of this select menu another select menu, like:

```
Item 0                                select menu       select menu   
Description Item 0
```

And this elements should be vertically aligned. Im not achieving this layout with the code below do you know how to fix?

working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/fne5xLfv/1/

The "Description Item 0" is not below "Item 0", the select menu is below the text not at the right and the elements are not vertically aligned.

Html:

```
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h5 class="text-heading-blue mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Title</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <span>Item 0</span>
              <span>Description Item 0</span>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <span>Item 1</span>
              <span>Description Item 1</span>
             <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
              <span>Item 2</span>
              <span>Description Item 2</span>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
              <form>
                <select class="custom-select form-control">
                  <option selected="">0</option>
                  <option>1</option>
                  <option>2</option>
                </select>
              </form>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="card-footer">

          <button type="button" class="float-right btn">Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi Jan, Links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code in the question itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is something like this what you need? If not, please provide more info and also your html and CSS tries...

```css
.list-group-item{
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-lg-8">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <h5 class="text-heading-blue mb-0 font-weight-semi-bold">Title</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <form>
            <label style="display:inline-block; width:150px">Item 0</label>      
            <select class="custom-select form-control" style="display:inline-block;width:200px">
              <option selected="">0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </form>
          <form>
            <label style="display:inline-block; width:150px">Description Item 0</label>
            <select class="custom-select form-control" style="display:inline-block;width:200px">
              <option selected="">0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </li>
        <br>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <form>
            <label style="display:inline-block; width:150px">Item 1</label>      
            <select class="custom-select form-control" style="display:inline-block;width:200px">
              <option selected="">0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </form>
          <form>
            <label style="display:inline-block; width:150px">Description Item 1</label>
            <select class="custom-select form-control" style="display:inline-block;width:200px">
              <option selected="">0</option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>
```

What I did:
Moved the `Span` inside the `form`, changed it to `Label`, added some inline style to Label and to `Select`, fixing the width and making it become inline aligned

Comment: Thanks, it is that, but the second select menu should be also at right of the first select menu.

Comment: well, now you have a good base of what to do, let's practice a little bit and try

Comment: probably just moving the second select right after the first one will be good (if not, take a look about 'float' and 'display').
If this answer helped you, please upvote and/or mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hi i think i understand what you want, check this.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>item 0</div>
      <div>description item 0</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="1" selected>1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="1" selected>1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>description item 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="1" selected>1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="1" selected>1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>description item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="1" selected>1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div>
        <select name="" id="">
          <option value="1" selected>1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

so bootstrap divide your screen into 12 columns, when you say `<div class="col-sm-4"></div>` this means you are giving 4 columns out of 12 to this div.